# How to rotate current carrying wires in 3d space using magpylib?

Tags: python, scipy, magpylib

Im using python's Magpylib library for magnetic field computation.

i've created a current conducting wire with vertices: `[(0,0,0)(1,0,0)]`

Now im trying to rotate it in such a way that its new vertices will be:
`[(0,0,0),(0,1,0)],[(0,0,0)(-1,0,0)],[(0,0,0)(0,-1,0)]`

This is where i currently stand:

```
wire=mag3.current.Line(current=10,vertices=[(0,0,0),(1,0,0)],position=(0,0,0))
print(wire.vertices)
wire=wire.rotate(R.from_euler('z',90, degrees=True),anchor=(0,0,0),increment=True)
print(wire.vertices)
```

i'm getting:

`[(0,0,0)(1,0,0)],[(0,0,0)(1,0,0)]`

while i'm looking to get: `[(0,0,0)(1,0,0)],[(0,0,0)(0,1,0)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How does it work?

It did not supposed to change, even tho it's a little unintuitive, but works like that: `move` and `rotate` method calls do not affect the `vertices`, but applies for `position` and `orientation`

```py
import magpylib as mag3
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

wire = mag3.current.Line(current=10, vertices=[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0)])
print(wire.vertices)
# [[0 0 0]
#  [1 0 0]]
print(wire.position)
# [0. 0. 0.]
print(wire.orientation.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True))
# [0. 0. 0.]

wire.move((1, 2, 3))
print(wire.vertices)
# [[0 0 0]
#  [1 0 0]]
print(wire.position)
# [1. 2. 3.]
print(wire.orientation.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True))
# [0. 0. 0.]

wire.rotate(R.from_euler('z', 45, degrees=True))
print(wire.vertices)
# [[0 0 0]
#  [1 0 0]]
print(wire.position)
# [1. 2. 3.]
print(wire.orientation.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True))
# [ 0.  0. 45.]
```

All of that is for objects that do not have any `vertices` like `Sphere`, you see, there's no way to define sphere rotation other than simply store it as a separate value. (tho why we would want to store rotation of the sphere is another question :] )

## Anyway, how can we achieve this?

But if you wanna see the effect of the rotation on the vertices you can do `wire.orientation.apply(wire.vertices)`

```py
import magpylib as mag3
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

wire = mag3.current.Line(current=10, vertices=[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0)])

wire.rotate(R.from_euler('z', 45, degrees=True))
print(wire.vertices)
# [[0 0 0]
#  [1 0 0]]
print(wire.orientation.apply(wire.vertices))
# [[0.         0.         0.        ]
#  [0.70710678 0.70710678 0.        ]]
print(wire.vertices)
# [[0 0 0]
#  [1 0 0]]
```

and if you wanna get the shift then just use `wire.vertices + wire.position`

```py
import magpylib as mag3
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

wire = mag3.current.Line(current=10, vertices=[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0)])

wire.move((1, 2, 3))
wire.move((4, 3, 2))
print(wire.vertices)
# [[0 0 0]
#  [1 0 0]]
print(wire.vertices + wire.position)
# [[5. 5. 5.]
#  [6. 5. 5.]]
print(wire.vertices)
# [[0 0 0]
#  [1 0 0]]
```

I don't know how this package works with simultaneous shift and rotation, and the question is not about it, so I hope that's enough for now.

Comment: @jacob if this answer helped you or you like it, please do not forget to [vote up and mark the answer as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the deep dive on those topics, it seems like the solution for my problem lies with orientation.apply, thank you very much!